# MySQL - wrapping multiple rows into one

Tags: mysql

I have this data set in MySQL where the records need to be collapsed into a single row, however, the number of columns to wrap around varies. Here's an example:

```
Id     Name                  Pre/Post    Attempt     Other Data
--     --------              --------    -------     ----------
1      James Owens              Pre         1          blah
1      James Owens              Post        1          blah
1      James Owens              Post        2          blah

2      Derek Williams           Post        1          blah
2      Derek Williams           Post        2          blah
2      Derek Williams           Post        3          blah

3      Sean Parker              Pre         1          blah

4      Miles Taylor             Pre         1          blah
4      Miles Taylor             Post        1          blah
4      Miles Taylor             Post        2          blah
4      Miles Taylor             Post        3          blah
4      Miles Taylor             Post        4          blah
```

The highest number of Attempts would be 4. I'd like the data to end up this way (or something close to this):

```
Id     Name                     Pre         Post      Post      Post      Post      Other Data
--     -------------            ---         ----      ----      ----      ----      ----------
1      James Owens               1           1         2                            blah
2      Derek Williams                        1         2         3                  blah
3      Sean Parker               1                                                  blah
4      Miles Taylor              1           1         2         3         4        blah
```

I know you're going to ask "What have you tried?" -- well, I haven't tried anything because I have no idea where to begin.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you simplify the data you want? Right now it looks like you want a query that can have variable columns. I knwo this is possible in sql server using dynamic sql but not so sure in mysql. Anyway it sounds like what you are doing could be done better? Could you not just have two columns pre and post and have the count of attempts? Are the values in the columns the number of attempts? or do they need to be summed up? e.g. is Derek Williams total post attempts 3?

Comment: Yes, the number in the column is the number of attempts. No, they don't need to be summed. I thought about simplifying the data using a VIEW, but unsure about that.

Comment: do you need the number of columns to be dynamic? can you not just have two columns? That query would be much simpler.

Comment: Are you talking about 1 for `Pre` and 1 for `Post`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ryan mentioned in the comment, you could have just two columns that store counts of pre and post attempts. You can achieve this by:

```
select distinct(tbl.id), name, pre_count.count, post_count.count, other_data
from `tbl` left join (select id, count(*) as count
                      from `tbl` where pre_post = 'pre' group by id) as pre_count
                      on tbl.id = pre_count.id
           left join (select id, count(*) as count
                      from `tbl` where pre_post = 'post' group by id) as post_count
                      on tbl.id = post_count.id
```

Comment: Yeap ... note I would rather do joins than the above syntax for readability.

Comment: I made the changes necessary to adapt to my situation and the query runs fine but comes up with 0 records. What, if anything, am I doing wrong?

Comment: The query only works if there is atleast one attempt for pre and post. Use left join to include those entries.

Comment: Also try using `where pre_post = 'Pre'`.